# django rest framework global pagination not working with ListCreateAPIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-generic-views, django-pagination

I have the following in my `settings.py`

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
     'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
     'PAGE_SIZE': 50
       }
```

`urls.py`

```
url(r'^dashboard/users$', views.UserList.as_view()),
```

And the View itself

```
class UserList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
     queryset = User.objects.all()
     serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

When i try to access `/dashboard/users/?page=1` I get a `404 error` with the following urls in the debug mode:

```
^dashboard/users$
^dashboard/users\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$
```

According to the Django rest frameworks's [pagination docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/):

> Pagination is only performed automatically if you're using the generic views or viewsets. If you're using a regular APIView, you'll need to call into the pagination API yourself to ensure you return a paginated response. See the source code for the mixins.ListModelMixin and generics.GenericAPIView classes for an example.

I am already using generic views here, then why doesn't this work?

Comment: You didn't set `PAGE_SIZE` in your `settings.py`

Comment: I had set that in code, while pasting it got left, i have update the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the helpfull suggestion from @neverwalkaloner , I Was still seeing a `404` error. I turned out that is was due to a url missmatch

I had to change my url definition from

```
url(r'^dashboard/users$', views.UserList.as_view())
```

to

```
url(r'^dashboard/users/$', views.UserList.as_view())
```

> The trailing `/` did the trick

Answer (score 2):

From description of [`LimitOffsetPagination`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#limitoffsetpagination):

> This pagination style mirrors the syntax used when looking up multiple database records. The client includes both a "limit" and an "offset" query parameter. The limit indicates the maximum number of items to return, and is equivalent to the page_size in other styles. The offset indicates the starting position of the query in relation to the complete set of unpaginated items.

So you need to pass `limit` and `offset` as GET argument if you want to use `LimitOffsetPagination`: `https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=400`

Or you can use [`PageNumberPagination`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/#pagenumberpagination) instead:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

Comment: Understood, but even after making the required changes, i'm seeing a 404 error. Do i need to pass anything special in the URL conf? Why doesn't the urls match?